# multiple GetJSON calls not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, call

I have some code that runs like this, and it works as intended.

```
<script>
$.getJSON(url1, function (data1) {
    $.getJSON(url2, function (data2) {
        $.getJSON(url3, function (data3) {

            //do stuff with data1, data2, data3
        });
    });    
});
</script>
```

I tried to streamline the calls like this

```
<script>
$.when(
    $.getJSON(url1),
    $.getJSON(url2),
    $.getJSON(url3),
).done(function(data1, data2, data3){
    //do stuff with data1, data2, data3
});
</script>
```

The first code works, but the second doesn't. I can't seem to get the second code to work. Is there something I'm missing?!

Answer (score -1):

Add a `then()` to each `$.getJSON` that returns the response data

```
$.when(
  $.getJSON('data.json').then(res => res),
  $.getJSON('data2.json').then(res => res),
  $.getJSON('data3.json').then(res => res)
).done(function(data1, data2, data3) {
    //do stuff with data1, data2, data3
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/O9naBuFOtoyKl6shVpWp?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

In your second example, data1, data2, and data3 are lists of length 3 containing the response text, status, and jqXHR object, rather than just being the JSON data like in the first example.

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON(url1),
    $.getJSON(url2),
    $.getJSON(url3),
).done(function(data1, data2, data3){
    //do stuff with data1[0], data2[0], data3[0]
});
```

Another thing to consider is that JQuery expects your return type to be JSON, so if your server response does not contain "Content-Type:application/json", the done callback won't fire.